# Is there any way I should change my call to a Javascript function when I use bind?

Tags: javascript

When I define a function like this:

```
  var town = 'Liverpool';

  foo = function(x,y){
           alert(x);
           alert(y);
           alert(this.town)
        }.bind(this);
```

I have learned that one way to pass the "this" into a function is to use .bind(this) if I'm using browsers IE9 and above.  However if I do this then does it mean I need to change the way I define the x and y parameters of my function?

Comment: No, you can call the function as usual foo(4,3)

Comment: Okay thanks. I was unsure of this as I saw .bind(this, arg1 etc. I did not understand why there were other arguments for .bind.

Comment: It's used to pass default arguments to the function. Check my answer, i have given one example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function just like foo(argument1, argument2)

The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

You can pass multiple arguments to bind() to make a function with pre-specified initial arguments. These arguments (if any) follow the provided this value and are then inserted at the start of the arguments passed to the target function, followed by the arguments passed to the bound function, whenever the bound function is called.

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]

//  Create a function with a preset leading argument
var leadingThirtysevenList = list.bind(undefined, 37);

var list2 = leadingThirtysevenList(); // [37]
var list3 = leadingThirtysevenList(1, 2, 3); // [37, 1, 2, 3]
```

[for further reading](http://dailyjs.com/2012/06/25/this-binding/)

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)